# How to come out of a deadlock in linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, deadlock

On a multi threading system, if two threads want to work on a shared memory after locking a mutex.

Thread A:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)  
.......   //Memory corruption or Assert and thread exits  
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
```

Thread B:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)  
.......  
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
```

If Thread A acquires the mutex first and exits due to memory corruption or assert, Thread B will be waiting forever causing a deadlock.

1. Is there a way/method i can use to come out from this kind of deadlock, once it happened?
2. Is there any other safer method similar to mutex that I can use?

Comment: Ensure that a thread has a list of all resources that need to be released on exit. Ensure that all resources are released on exit.

Comment: If Thread A exits due to "memory corruption", you've already got undefined behavior and nothing can help you. IIRC assertion failure will exit the process, not just the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ROBUST` attribute on a mutex. With a robust mutex, if the thread that acquired it exits for some reason without unlocking it, the mutex enters a special state where the next thread that attempts to lock it will get `EOWNERDEAD`.

It is then the responsibility of that thread to cleanup any inconsistent state. If recovery is possible, the thread shall call `pthread_mutex_consistent(3)` any time before `pthread_mutex_unlock(3)`, so that the other threads can use it as before. If recovery is not possible, the mutex should be unlocked without calling `pthread_mutex_consistent(3)`, causing it to enter an unusable state where the only permissible operation is to destroy it.

Note that the mutex is locked even if `EOWNERDEAD` was returned (I think it's the only condition under which `pthread_mutex_lock(3)` returns with an error but locks the mutex).

To set the `ROBUST` attribute, use `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(3)` after initializing the mutex attributes instance. Remember that this must be done before initializing the mutex. So, something like:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attrs;

if (pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attrs) != 0) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
if (pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mutex_attrs, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST) != 0) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mutex_attrs) != 0) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
int lock_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

if (lock_res == EOWNERDEAD) {
    /* Someone died before unlocking the mutex
     * We assume there's no cleanup to do
     */
    if (pthread_mutex_consistent(&mutex) != 0) {
        /* Handle error... */
    }
} else if (lock_res != 0) {
    /* Some other error, handle it here */
}

/* mutex is locked here, do stuff... */

if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) != 0) {
    /* Handle error */
}
```

For more info you can see the manpage for [pthread_mutex_consistent(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_consistent.html) and [pthread_mutex_getrobust(3) / pthread_mutex_setrobust(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want threads to clean up after themselves, you generally need to ask for it or do it yourself.

You can for example use [`pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) to ensure cleanup happens if the thread exits using `pthread_exit()` or if it is cancelled (by way of [`pthread_cancel()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)).

The downsides of this API are that each pair of calls must be in the same function and in the same lexical nesting level (e.g. In your thread's entry function).
I can't tell if you're allowed to cancel a thread from within a signal handler, so you might not be able to handle this using that API, and these types of errors and assertions typically make the entire process exit (Although, presumably if you're implementing your own assert variant, it could call `pthread_exit()`).

There do exist other lock types that unlock automatically (e.g. `flock()` locks, or robust mutexes as shown by Filipe Gonçalves) when the owner dies, but you have little guarantee of state consistency in cases where someone lost a lock and will need to clean up after them

Comment: This doesn't exactly fit here though. How would you know if you had to release the mutex? Generally you don't know where in the code you are when the cleanup handlers are invoked. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves If this actually applies to your code, you'd probably have something along the line of `lock(mtx); cln_push(unlockfnc, mtx); /* Do stuff */ ; cln_pop(0); unlock(mtx) /*Could also pass non-zero  to pop instead*/ ;`. Cleanup handlers are stacked and one would expect the inner code to use these as well to return to a consistent state (and/or signal that it is inconsistent).